# AGOL tiling creates multiple labels

Tags: arcgis-online, web-mapping, tiles, arcgis-pro

I create a webmap and use publish it on ArcGIS Online. Unfortunately the tiling engine of AGOL creates multiple labels for the same item. How can I prevent this?
Same label problems occured, when I created the tiles locally.
[image: multiple labels]

[image: single label when zoomed out]
The labeling works great in ArcGIS Pro, BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at annotation featureclasses to avoid this.

Per [How do I avoid duplicate labels in my cache?](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/common-caching-questions.htm#anchor7)

> If you are using a dynamic labeling engine in your map document to
>   place labels (as opposed to annotation), you might occasionally see
>   duplicate labels in your cache tiles. These should not occur any more
>   frequently than 4,096 pixels in any direction. You can eliminate all
>   duplicate labels by using annotation. When you use annotation, labels
>   are associated with one point on the map and duplicates do not occur.

Much more detail in this [help topic](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/labels-in-map-caches.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about AGOL, but Tilemill, which uses the mapnik renderer, uses metatiles for this purpose. I guess there should be an equivalent in AGOL. See for explanation: https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/metatiles/